# How to represent large number without the E form in Scala

Tags: scala, numbers

I deal with numbers of this form `1.446267186999E7` and i want to represent them without `E`.
For example `1.446267186999E7` i want it to be `14462671.86999` . 
How do i convert it to this form without getting the :

```
error: integer number too large.
```

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a formatting problem if you store it as a double.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
val d: Double = 1.446267186999E7
val decimalFormat: DecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#####")
println(decimalFormat.format(d))
```

should give you 14462671.86999

Comment: Note that this will truncate your number to 5 digits behind the comma.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
BigDecimal(1.446267186999E7).toString
```

The `BigDecimal.toString` method will give you the string representation of the number in decimal form.

Answer (score 0):

You probably after [BigDecimal](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal). In terms of string formatting, look at the .format method, or printf